# correct spelling of "carruffel" (fuzz, hustle, all that jazz)

Tags: word-request, spelling

I faintly remember learning a word that means an *arbitrary hubbub* of things, *all the to do*, *a minor inconvenience*, etc., I'm not really sure. I thought it was  ca. "carruffel", but that does not exist. Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: "Kerfluffle" is one version I've seen. But this is a very informal word, so you'll likely see other spellings as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [**kerfuffle**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kerfuffle):

> *plural* **kerfuffles**
>
> : a disturbance or commotion typically caused by a dispute or conflict
>
> // In all the *kerfuffle*, nobody seemed to have noticed Harry, which suited him perfectly.
>   — J. K. Rowling
>
> // It's not the only school with dress code issues; almost every week there's a local story about some *kerfuffle* over what kids wear to school.
>   — Belinda Luscombe

Comment: Perhaps worth adding that this (as far as I'm aware) is primarily a British English word, and relatively informal.